# System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException:

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am facing crash issue in following line of code :

int bytesRead = await this.stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, token);

Error Log :

{System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Security.Interface.TlsException: Unknown Secure Transport error `DecryptionFail'.
  at Mono.AppleTls.AppleTlsContext.CheckStatusAndThrow (Mono.AppleTls.SslStatus status, Mono.AppleTls.SslStatus[] acceptable) [0x00096] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.AppleTls/AppleTlsContext.cs:127
  at Mono.AppleTls.AppleTlsContext.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x0009f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.AppleTls/AppleTlsContext.cs:810 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessRead (Mono.Net.Security.BufferOffsetSize userBuffer) [0x00011] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:632 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncReadRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:320 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest+d__24.MoveNext () [0x000ff] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:221 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:447 
  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest+d__23.MoveNext () [0x00046] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/AsyncProtocolRequest.cs:187 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+d__58.MoveNext () [0x001b9] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MobileAuthenticatedStream.cs:380 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/

Thanks for the help

Comment: Which HttpClientHandler are you using?

Comment: Its a TCP communication. In the above code this.stream is instance of the Stream class.  I am working in app that communicates with hardware device via wifi mode.

Comment: @KartikKaremani When the TlsException is thrown, what does the device log show? I'm assuming you are connecting to a device that is not using TLS/SSL, but...?

Comment: @SushiHangover it could be a SSLStream. Unclear from the question though